# ArrayAdapter notifyDataSetChanged() not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an array adapter and associated code that worked fine when in an activity. I'm migrating to using fragments and now it doesn't update. Using action bar tabs, if I go to my tab the first time the list populates and shows fine. If I go to a different tab and come back, the list is populated but the list view is empty.

If I add something to the list during the first visit, the list is updated fine. If I leave, come back, and add an item it does not show up. An item is added to the list by saving an image to the database and then calling `refreshGallery()`.

```
@Override
public onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inspection_images, container, false);
  mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.inspection_images_list);
  setInspectionImages(mInspection.getInspectionImages());

  return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  refreshGallery();
}

public void refreshGallery() {
  mInspectionImages = mInspection.getInspectionImages();
  setInspectionImages(mInspectionImages());
}

public void setInspectionImages(ArrayList<InspectionImage> images) {
  if (null == mArrayAdapter) {
    mArrayAdapter = new InspectionImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.inspection_image_list_item, images);
    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
  }
  else {
    mArrayAdapter.clear();
    addInspectionImagesToList(images);
  }
}

public void addInspectionImagesToList(ArrayList<InpsectionImage> images) {
  mArrayAdapter.addAll(images);
  mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I don't think the given problem comes from the adapter nor its population (although it could be improved), maybe something left in the activity or you omitted to transfer to the fragment. For one thing, I'm pretty sure the `onCreateView()` implementation you pasted here isn't the one you compiled since it doesn't declare a return type, but in any case make sure it returns `v`. Pasting a bit more code and the one you actually compile and run with may help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The only things missing from `onCreateView` is some button listener setups. I added the `return v;`.

Comment: That's still not the code you're running... Anyway, going out on a limb then, are you sure you don't re-create a `mListView` in `OnCreateView()` but still populate the previous `mArrayAdapter` (which is set to the previous `mListView`) in `setInspectionImages()` ?

Comment: Is `onCreateView()` called each time the tab is loaded? Where should I initialize `mListView` then? `onCreateView()` is the first chance I get to initialize it, but I could do it later.

Comment: It depends on how you implemented `onTabSelected()`... I'll assume you copy-pasted from the Android developers guide and post and answer accordingly, because if so that may be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've implemented `onTabSelected()` as per the [Android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs), i.e.:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
        mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
}
```

What happens when you show the fragment the *first* time:

1. in `onTabSelected()`, `mFragment` is null and a new one is instantiated
2. the *created* fragment is attached to `mActivity`
3. the fragment's `onCreateView()` is called, `mListView` is created, `mArrayAdapter` is created and populated and attached to `mListView` and `mListView` is returned
4. the list view items are visible and everything is dandy

What happens after you switched out to another tab then switched back to that same one:

1. in `onTabSelected()`, `mFragment` exists so only `ft.attach(mFragment);` is executed (on the same fragment as before, i.e. **no new fragment is created**)
2. the *existing* fragment is attached to `mActivity` once more
3. the fragment's `onCreateView()` is called (check the [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) and what happens when a fragment is [attached](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach(android.app.Fragment)) if you wonder why), a **new `mListView`** is created, `setInspectionImages()` is called and the **old `mArrayAdapter`** is present so it's populated but never attached to the new `mListView`
4. the `mListView` shown in the layout doesn't have any adapter attached, and all of your actions populate a now unrelated array adapter

For one thing you don't have to repopulate the adapter on each `onResume()`. Do it once at creation time (I would put it in `onActivityCreated()`) and just update it when necessary.

And then you don't need to check for the existence of `mArrayAdapter`, just create it every time in `onActivityCreated()`.

If you want to keep your current design though, just be sure to nullify its reference when the list view disappears:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView () {
    mArrayAdapter = null;
    mListView = null;
}
```